# How to abort pending page transitions in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with a jQuery Mobile website on a slow connection.
Imagine a simple page with 2 buttons (just regular data-role="buttons")

- Button 1 goes to Page1
- Button 2 goes to Page2.

When clicking Button 1, an AJAX call get's fired to get Page1.
However on a slow environment you'll still be able to click Button 2, before the page loads Page1. Because of that, the request to Page2 is also being fired and causing the page to flicker from Page1 to Page2.

Technically this makes sense since jQuery Mobile is using AJAX calls for it's page transitions.
Is there any way to abort all other page requests once a page request is being made?
In other words: Is there a way to only make the last click 'count'?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you `disable` the button once clicked?

Comment: @Omar: Because if the user clicks the wrong button by accident, they should have the opportunity to click the correct button before the page is loaded. Like normal non-ajax page transitions would work.

Comment: Hmmm...you mean you want to add a delay before executing any Ajax call?

Comment: @Omar: I don't want to add a delay. The delay is already there, because of the network and server latency. The whole point is that clicking a second button (firing a second ajax request) before the first one is completed, will cause another page transition after the first page transition from the first ajax call. Any ideas on how to abort the first ajax call when firing another?